# content of second activity doesnt show when moving to it from listview

Tags: android

I have a listview with items in it, I have created a setonItemClicklistener to make the items clickable and in that, I have created an intent when clicked on an item a new activity is supposed the show
  the problem is when the new activity has opened the layout(design) of the second activity doesn't show.

The class Moments activity

```
public class MomentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextMessage;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_moments:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MomentsActivity.this, MomentsActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_addmoment:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MomentsActivity.this, AddMomentActivity.class);
                intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent2);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_moments);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    mList = this.findViewById(R.id.my_listview);
    manageListView();
    mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MomentsActivity.this, singlemomentactivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.triptracker_logo);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);

}

DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editTitle, editDescription, editLocation;
Button btnAddData;
Button btnViewAll;
SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA; //Adapts/Handles the data for the listview
ListView mList;
Cursor mCsr;

int[] item_layout_ids_for_list = new int[]{
        R.id.textview_name,
        R.id.textview_description,
        R.id.textview_location
};

String[] columns_to_list = new String[]{
        DatabaseHelper.COL_2,
        DatabaseHelper.COL_3,
        DatabaseHelper.COL_5
};

private void manageListView() {
    mCsr = myDb.getAllData();
    if (mSCA == null) {
        // Builds the Adapter for the List
        mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.mylistview_item, mCsr,
                columns_to_list,
                item_layout_ids_for_list,
                0
        );
        mList.setAdapter(mSCA); // Ties the Adapter to the ListView
    } else {
        mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr); // Refresh the List
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mCsr.close();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    manageListView();
}}
```

The class singlemomentactivity

```
public class singlemomentactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_moments:
            Intent intent = new Intent(singlemomentactivity.this, MomentsActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_moments);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}}






<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MomentsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="615dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line in singlemomentactivity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_moments);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_moments); //check with your layout name
```

Comment: Keep Learning.@A.Rizgar